# How do I horizontally center this in Android (RelativeLayout)?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/exercise_name_label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:text="Curls"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
```

And I want the text to be aligned at the bottom of the 32dp and center horizontally..currently it's not centering horizontally:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OPTION 1:
You should adjust gravity to center_horizontal|bottom =)

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/exercise_name_label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:text="Curls"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />
```

OPTION 2:
You should adjust width to wrap_content and center_horizontally in parent =)

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/exercise_name_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:text="Curls"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: Can you show me code of option 2 please? I tried it but can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_centerInParent="true"` is what you want. But I must say that you should not use Relative Layout. Linear Layout is more steady in my opinion.

If you want to change it to Linear Layout you can use `android:layout_gravity="center"`.

Answer (score 0):

Set these attribute to your TextView:

```
<!-- It will make your layout center horizontal relative to parent -->
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

<!-- It will draw your text from center of the area assigned to textview-->
android:gravity="center"
```